# Detect if MongoDb Database will be created / was created

Tags: c#, mongodb

We're using one database for each tenant. So our code looks like this:

```
 var collection = MongoClient.GetDatabase(accountId).GetCollection("mycol");
```

We don't know at this place if the database already exists or not. Same for the collection.

Problem: I want to create an index. To be able to do this, I need to have some "event" when a new database or collection was created, so I know that I have to create the index for it.

Options:

- If there's a chance to get an error/exception/null for GetDatabase() or GetCollection() calls I could handle this and "prepare" the db/collection. Problem: There is no error or whatever that allows me to check if it's new / does not exist?
- Driver Events: I saw there are events in the driver (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/reference/driver_core/events/) but that seems to be the wrong place?
- Change Events: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/ looks not so bad, there's a dropDatabase event - but no createDatabase event.
- Manually check before insert/updates. That would require an additional request to the database. Bad idea…
- ???

Is there any way to get a trigger when a db or collection was created?

Comment: I'd fully expect `GetDatabase` return `null` if it can't find the DB if it doesn't throw an exception. The "new" check is irrelevant in the sense that the index is a one-time operation, it should be created as part of the DB setup. In other words, if you have a DB you can assume the index is there, otherwise create both.

Comment: @James - thanks, but GetDatabase() will always return the db object. You're right that one could call it cleaner to create the database when a new account was created but that's not as easy as it sounds: Account management is a different service running in a different data center and if we need the database depends on what features are enabled for an account. If there's no way to check if a db exists, we'll go that route.

Comment: A trigger doesn't seem reasonable (from server(s) to client(s)?). But can't you use MongoClient.ListDatabaseNames ?

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. "trigger" might not be the best word - I mean "something that allows me to check if the database I requested using GetDatabase() exists". An exception or null return in GetDatabase() for example. ListDatabaseNames would work in theory but in practice I cannot list all database before every write request.

Comment: In my case, I do that kind of operation only once (using a Lazy initializer). Of course that won't work if the db is deleted during the normal course of operations, but this would be very unusual (and in this case, you can catch error)

Comment: @SimonMourier - yes, I fear we'll need to setup this from the beginning. I was hoping, we can delay this until we need to propagate "tenant deleted" events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between MongoDB and other RDBMS-like databases is that in MongoDB databases and collections are created automatically. Documentation says that:

> If a database does not exist, MongoDB creates the database when you first store data for that database

So you won't get any error when you're trying to hit the database that does not exist. What's more there is no "DatabaseExists" method in C# driver but you can create your own method. To check if the database exists you can use [db.stats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/index.html) admin command which returns some important statistics about particular database.

Sample result of `db.stats` may look like below:

```
{
    "db" : "databasene2",
    "collections" : 0,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 0,
    "avgObjSize" : 0,
    "dataSize" : 0,
    "storageSize" : 0,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 0,
    "indexSize" : 0,
    "fileSize" : 0,
    "fsUsedSize" : 0,
    "fsTotalSize" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So you can create an extension method in C# which will return `null` if there are no collections and indexes:

```
public static IMongoDatabase GetDatabaseIfExists(this IMongoClient client, string databaseName)
{
    var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    var command = "{ dbStats: 1, scale: 1 }";
    var dbStats = database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
    var databaseExists = dbStats["collections"].AsInt32 > 0 || dbStats["indexes"].AsInt32 > 0;

    return databaseExists ? database : null;
}
```

usage:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
var db = mongoClient.GetDatabaseIfExists("dbThatNotExists"); //returns null
```

Similarly you can create another method taking advantage of [collStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/index.html) command, MongoDB C# driver throws `MongoCommandException` in this case, try:

```
public static IMongoCollection<T> GetCollectionIfExists<T>(this IMongoDatabase database, string collectionName)
{
    var command = $"{{ collStats: \"{collectionName}\", scale: 1 }}";
    try
    {
        database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
        return database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    }
    catch(MongoCommandException e) when (e.ErrorMessage.EndsWith("not found."))
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously you don't have to run those methods every time you need to access the database. You could run them once and then cache existing database names in memory and use `GetDatabase` directly.

Comment: You don't have to create specific methods, the official C# driver already has client.ListDatabaseNames  and database.ListCollectionNames already.

Comment: @SimonMourier I know but I believe that it's better to explicitly call for single database / collection info than querying the names

Comment: Thanks @mickl. It's this auto create behavior that confuses me. I'm fine with it, but if it auto creates something and a "clean create" includes additional actions (like indexes) the system should tell me somehow that it did this auto create. After this "auto create" the db was partly created (only the db but no indexes) and that's the problem here. While your answer looks much better than listing all (thousands) databases - it's still an extra request and something I would prefer not to use in production. I wonder if there's no real solution for auto create + indexes?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen this is where I can see the advantage of this solution - you get predictable number of bytes instead of listing everything. I remember that I had to design an architecture for a system in PaaS model with DB per tenant some time ago. It ended up having a "metadata" table which contained the info about all tenant databases and a lot of caching then to avoid checking db status with every call so I suppose you need something similar.

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, this is a solution but you can't predict the number of bytes you need to pull as this is a multitenant system and the number of databases will grow. Therefore I think that `dbStats` is more efficient way of figuring out if the database exists

Comment: While I was looking for a solution without an additional request to mongodb, this seems to be the best available solution - let's accept it ;-)  @SimonMourier thanks for adding ListCollectionNames which could be a good solution when filling a cache or similar.